# Biquad to 4quad filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I have a BandPass Biquad filter which expression is:

```
Result    = Nominator[0] * Input + FState[0];
State[0] = Nominator[1] * Input - Denominator[1] * Result + State[1];
State[1] = Nominator[2] * Input - Denominator[2] * Result;
```

How can I improve the order of this filter without making a ladder of two identical filters?
Can I save some calculations for that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "improve the order"?  There is no such thing as a "4quad filter".

Comment: Ehm, sorry. You're right and the title of this question shows my lack of experience about DSP; What I was trying to ask is if it's possibile to ehnance response of this filter without plain duplicating the formula. It's a math thing, but I was wondering if it's possible..(Maybe raising the length of the FState array).

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to do direct implementations of higher order filters, they tend to require extremely high-precision arithmetic, so most filter designers prefer to factor hi-order filters into series of biquads.

There is a good tutorial at https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/filters.html